# Why do I need to run ldconfig everytime I put .so library into directories like /usr/local/lib if set by config files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/?

Tags: centos, docker, libraries, ldconfig, ld.so.conf

I am running centos 6.10 in docker. As is described in the title, I set `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/lib64` in a conf file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. I need to run `ldconfig` everytime when I put .so library into `/usr/local/lib` or it will not be found (when compiling Python 3). However, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64` (without writing them to conf files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`) does not need any additional steps after putting the libs. What causes this?

By the way, why directories like `/lib` and `/usr/lib` are not set in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`?

Answer (score 0):

When an app is run via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=PATH app` glibc will scan all the files in the the specified directories.

When you're not using this flag only cached libraries (`/etc/ld.so.cache`) are opened to speed up the process. Imagine you need to run a certain application 100K times in a row and each time all the directories have to be rescanned. It might slow everything to a crawl.